# Pixel 3 XL Verizon unlock bootloader. OEM not highlighted in developer

Tags: bootloader-lock, verizon, google-pixel-3-xl

My **Pixel 3 XL** was using OS 11 Verizon. Without asking, it updated to OS 12.

Ever since my system app keeps crashing, it will not stay connected to the internet and overall, ruined the phone. Being Verizon I can't unlock the bootloader either. I need help. I can sideload or adb/fastboot but I want to install Custom ROM.

Comment: If I remember correctly all Verizon devices are locked forever as Verizon disables unlocking for all their devices. If you plan to root the device never buy a Verizon phone.

Comment: I am sorry to say there is no other workaround than factory reset